# Changing a custom content type's icon, possibly with javascript

Tags: javascript, content-type, file-icons

I have a document library with multiple cusotom content types derived from "Document Set".
They all show up with the same icon in a general list view.

Here's what I would like to do:
I'd like to change the icon in my list view to be different depending on the content type of each item. For example my content type "Car" would get a car-icon, my "Bike", would get a bike-icon.

I know that Sharepoint does not allow me to do this out of the box.
How would I do that using java script? (maybe I can even use something like  these https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ ?)

Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated...

Comment: Lame proposal: A read only field on each content type that store the url of the icon, then work up from there? I know it is only a guess, I will try to elaborate more as soon as I get some time.

Comment: Use JSLink and override the field rending of the particular view. see example: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSlink is indeed a great way to do this.

Here is a good tuturial that got me started: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/

Comment: This is actually a nice article because it covers a general but basic case of doing some csr with jslink